# Applet referencing to localhost gets blocked if html is on shared drive

Tags: java, applet

I have an html file with applet code like

```
<applet code="myapplet.class" archive="http://localhost:8080/myapplets.jar"width="350" height="350"></applet>
```

The applet loads fine if  the html file is local to the machine but if that html file is on shared drive (windows) and if html file opened ( so that the address  in the  address bar is 
\X.X.X.X\testhtml\myapplethost.html )  then
While applet is trying to load  , this exception is thrown

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: http://localhost:8080/myapplets.jar
```

I have added both the

```
http://localhost:8080  and  file:\\X.X.X.X\testhtml
```

to the exception list. Have lowered the security  to the lowest possible (i.e Medium)  in java control panel (JRE 1.7 upate 67)  but this applet keeps getting blocked. Is there any settign that can help here to allow the access to applet from the shared location? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `archive` parameter of the applet can only reference archives (e.g. jar files) from the same source the applet was started. Here is the quote from the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html):

> For security reasons, the applet's class loader can read only from the same codebase from which the applet was started. This means that archives in *archiveList* must be in the same directory as, or in a subdirectory of, the codebase.

If you load the HTML page from a shared drive, the `archive` attribute of the `applet` tag in the HTML file should not point to `http://localhost:8080/myapplets.jar`. Most likely this is just a mistake (you forgot to change it or you forgot to use relative URL).

Just change the `archive` attribute to a relative URL and it will work. Something like this:

```
<applet code="myapplet.class" archive="myapplets.jar" width="350" height="350">
</applet>
```

Absoulte URLs are always a bad idea and this is especially true for applet archives.

Comment: the applet jar is actually hosted  to the localhost:8080  and the html file will could be anywhere and needs to  load the  applet .. most of the time it would be local  but it can be on shared drive as well .. so  is there no way I can make this applet be allowed to load ?  I can't change the archive  because it has to be from localhost:8080 only

Comment: As you can read in the quoted doc, you can't. You have to ship the jar with the HTML page. What you can do is host the HTML also on localhost (I assume you do) and tell others to open the HTML from your computer and not from the shared drive. Of course change `localhost` to your computer's name in the `archive` attribute (because `localhost` is only valid on your own computer).

Answer (score 0):

Used shared drive  path (like Z:  instead of  \server ) and it works.